# python requests module - set key to null

Tags: python, python-requests

from the requests documentation :

> ### Remove a Value From a Dict Parameter
>
> Sometimes you’ll want to omit session-level keys from a dict parameter. To do this, you simply set that key’s value to None in the method-level parameter. It will automatically be omitted.

I need the data with key's value as **None** to take the Json value **null** instead of being removed.
Is it possible ?

edit : This seems to happen with my request data keys. While they are not session-level the behaviour of removing is still the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no session-level JSON parameter, so the merging rules don't apply.

In other words, the `json` keyword argument to the `session.request()` method is passed through unchanged, `None` values in that structure do not result in keys being removed.

The same applies to `data`, there is no session-level version of that parameter, no merging takes place. If `data` is set to a dictionary, any keys whose value is set to `None` are ignored. Set the value to `''` if you need those keys included with an empty value.

The rule does apply when merging `headers`, `params`, `hooks` and `proxies`.

Comment: Indeed, I messed up between session-leveled keys and my datas keys!
question is edited

Comment: @paulc: `data` is not being merged; instead, keys whose values are set to `None` are ignored. Use an empty string instead if you need the key to show up with no value.

Comment: @paulc: but setting `data` to a dictionary has nothing to do with JSON data, there is no concept of `null` in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data` encodings.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenments! Although I can seem to put null data through the django rest framework api I'm using, it seems to be cheating somewhere. I'll have to see on this side. Found a related thread [link]https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-rest-framework/gYGaFko27Vk[/link]